# How do I add a language keyword in Boo to let 'when' behave as an 'if'

Tags: boo

I cannot seem to figure out how I can add the 'when' keyword to [BOO](http://boo.codehaus.org/) which should behave as an 'if'. I figure I could make a method, but then I cannot move the when around like I can with if. Any pointers would be appreciated.

-Mark

Answer (score 11):

This would do what you want:

```
import Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast
import Boo.Lang.Compiler.MetaProgramming

macro when:
    return [|
        if $(when.Arguments[0]):
            $(when.Block)
    |]

x = 1
when x == 1:
    print "x equals one"
when x == 2:
    print "x equals two"
```

Btw, feel free to (also) ask on the Boo mailing-list to get (more) answers quicker ;)

http://groups.google.com/group/boolang/

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, now only if SO would send me an e-mail notifying you answered it.

Comment: Hehe, well that's why I advised you to subscribe to the Boo mailing-list for your future questions (or just to keep up with the updates of the language ;) )

Comment: Good answer.
Note that if you also want to support "when... else", it'll get trickier.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a job for a macro.  From the page you linked to, it seems that Boo has syntactic macros.

As an aside note, why do you need an exact duplicate of an existing functionality?

Comment: The page linked to was an edit :) I saw that and all but for the if functionality I was unable to get it to work.

Reason why I want it is for a DSL (readability).